# GameSparks Post High Score From GameSparks Event

Tags: gamesparks

I have a system in my game that saves the players progress locally when they are offline. However, once they reconnect I push a batch of saved level progress to the server for processing. One of the attributes I am trying to process server side is the level score. How do I add a score to a running total in GameSparks? I have not been able to find any documentation on how if possible to do this.

Thank you,
Travis Pettry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do in CloudCode is call the flowing:

```
Spark.logEvent("EventToSetScoreOnLeaderboard", {"attr1": value, "attr2": value});
```